# Sql query not working when i use the where condition in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have used a datalist for displaying data from database. The code for it is:

```
<div id="ccont">
      <asp:DataList ID="mydatalist" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
           product:<asp:Label ID="lbl1"     Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"product") %>' runat="server" />
           <br/>
            price:<asp:Label ID="lbl2" Text='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"price") %>' runat="server" />

        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:DataList>
  </div>
```

And its corresponding .cs file has the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sq.connection();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sub_catTbl where sid = 1 " , sq.con);

    SqlDataReader sd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    sd.Read();

    mydatalist.DataSource = sd;
    mydatalist.DataBind();

    sq.con.Close();
}
```

This SQL query gives no output nor gives any error. When I replace SQL query with:

```
select * from sub_catTbl
```

It works. The output is:

[image]

So how do I make the SQL query with `WHERE` condition  work?

Note: It's not working for `where name='abc'` as well.

**EDIT**: OK I have executed this query

```
 select * from sub_catTbl where sid = 1
```

and it works fine. Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Following @FeliceM's comment, can you show any of the data that comes back from plain `select * sub_catTbl` - even if you have to massage or scrub it a bit?  Also, what is `sub_catTbl`'s column list with data types?

Comment: Do you even have data where sid = 1 and name = 'abc'?

Comment: You should try because I do not see evident errors in the query itself. Are you sure the query can return data? Always try the queries in Sql MS to make sure they return what you need instead of blaming the code.

Comment: Yes with select * from sub_catTbl I am able to display data with above code.The result i get is product:ambey 
price:123
product:bridge 
price:666
product:jagadamba 
price:332
product:panchakanya 
price:6574. The data type of sid is int and others are nvarchar(50).

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen yes i do have those datas.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen i have run the query in the sql server management studio and it works .SO WHAT NOW?

Comment: Sum1, what we can see is only what you post. The record you show now in SQL MS is not present in those you posted before than I can only agree with Allan answer. There is something wrong and you are not helping to solve your problem. Make sure you are querying the same db because of what I said above and if you ask for help be helpful and give the results correctly otherwise there is no point.

Comment: @FeliceM I am truely seeking for help.Just imagine yourself in my place, the query works fine without where clause and when i put where clause it dosent work.I didnt know how to run query in sql server management studion but i figured out and ran the query and it is showing the output.You dont know how fraustrated i am and you guys are not helping insted you are just demoralizing me.I am working on aproject alone and i am already runnung out of time.I have no wrong intension.What wolud i get by trying to show you guys wrong.By the way i can mail you my whole project if you can actually HELP.

Comment: @Aristos  actually the list is long..so i have cropped to show just some part of output.Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: And by the way what ever i select sid = 1 or 2 or any data available in database..its not working at all.

Comment: Try this `select * from sub_catTbl where [sid] = 1` on your query

Comment: You do know we're trying to help you here for free, so acting out is not exactly a great motivator to continue to help you... ? Anyway - what is your connection string in sq? Are you sure you're connecting to the right database compared to the one in management studio? Try putting [] around sid? Also what happens if you change your `where`statement to `where product = 'ambey'`?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen This is my connection string string: str = @"Data Source=SUMAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=E-market;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";       And i have tried where product ='ambey' or any other data availabe in database but it is not working.[sid] is not working as well.

Comment: I suggest you now learn how to use `SQL Profiler`. This lets you monitor the database and capture the exact query that is being submitted in each case. This will tell you exactly what is submitted and confirm that it is running against the same database and schema.

Comment: I suspect you might have a connection leak as you do not dispose your datareader. So to debug this issue; 1) Try wrapping your datareader (sd) in a `using` clause (always a good idea). 2) instead of binding it to your datalist try and just use a `while (sd.read())` and do something like a `response.write(sd[0])`. Then it's easier for you to debug the reader.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen   When i use `while(sd.read())` and do `response.write(sd[0])` while keeping my query `select * from sub_catTable where [sid] = 1`,it prints 1.

Comment: So this means your query is fine, the problem is somewhere else in your web code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same problem. Just remove the sd.Read() line and everything works great.

For further reference see https://unschoolingcode.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/my-computer-is-playing-video-on-its-own/ and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719635(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score -2):

You didn't open the connection. Try to use `sq.con.open();`.

Comment: And tell us how then the query can return data with "select * from sub_catTbl" ?

Comment: there is nothing wrong in this code except opening the connection. As you asked he can read the data using  sd.Read();

Comment: I have open the sqlconnection.You see the "sq". This is actually an object of sql_con clas.And you can see sq.connection().The connection is a function where i have already opened the connection.Its code is:  public void connection()
    {
        string str = @"Data Source=SUMAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=E-market;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
        con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
    }

Comment: @FeliceM I have edited the question to display the result returned when i am not using the WHERE clause.